# Gremlin query output to CSV file

Tags: graph, export-to-csv, gremlin, janusgraph

I want to save the output returned by gremlin query to a CSV file with column names as labels of property and rows as values:

Query:

```
g.V().as('v1').outE().as('e').inV().as('v2').select('v1','e','v2').by(valueMap()).limit(1)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "v1": {
            "label_A": [
                "A"
            ] 
        },
        "e": {
            "label_E": "E"
        },
        "v2": {
            "label_B": [
        “B"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Csv file required:

```
label_A,labelB,label_E
A,B,E //row1
.,.,. //row2 
etc
```

Comment: You question is more on how to convert JSON data to CSV, right?

Comment: Actually the data is huge, so I want to store the output to a file.CSV will be most appropriate format. JSON will also work, but console doesn't return JSON.So, thinking on running a groovy script which will run mutiple queries one after other, these must be added to file(csv).

Answer (score 1):

While it was written for Amazon Neptune, there's very little about this tool that is specific to Neptune:

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-export

See in particular:

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/blob/master/neptune-export/docs/export-pg-from-queries.md

Comment: I am using janusgraph and cassandra, don't think it will work

Comment: If JanusGraph behaves like a Gremlin server that you'd normally connect to using a Gremlin client via Websockets, then this may still work. It just uses a regular Java Gremlin client under the hood.

Comment: ./neptune-export.sh export-pg-from-queries -e 127.0.0.1:8182 -d . -q data="g.V().limit(1).valueMap()"
Error: Unable to access jarfile export-pg-from-queries 
127.0.0.1:8182 is gremlin server address. Tried the above but not working. Please share the steps.